# Adding touch screen driver to Wandboard, i2c device registration

Tags: linux, touch, linux-device-driver, i2c

First I must to tell you, I am not really from electronics background, I have very rough knowledge about Linux drivers, I2C, touch screens, etc.

**Problem background**

My Wandboard was previously working with Fusion 7 touch display worked with Prism touch screen driver, already provided by Wandboard.
As per my new requirement, **I have got Ilitek touch screen which I am trying get it working with my Wandboard dual (i.MX6-Cortex-A9, Linux Kernel:3.0.35).**

I got following Ilitek touch screen driver files under folder *ilitek_limv3_0_9*.

- ilitek_lim.c
- ilitek.h
- ilitek_update.c
- ilitek_i2c.idc

I compiled the driver into Linux kerenl as a built-in module, tried to run on the board but failed. The driver doesn't appear in `/dev/input`.
I debuged the kerenl code a bit, and found that the code doesn't reach to driver's `probe` function, instead it fails in device binding (i2c device registration). Just then I come to know about Device tree.

I looked into following dts files (which I believe my Wandboard is using), putting little i2c configuration present in the files here.

*imx6qdl.dtsi*

```
i2c1: i2c@021a0000 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    compatible = "fsl,imx6q-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
    reg = <0x021a0000 0x4000>;
    interrupts = <0 36 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_I2C1>;
    status = "disabled";
};

i2c2: i2c@021a4000 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    compatible = "fsl,imx6q-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
    reg = <0x021a4000 0x4000>;
    interrupts = <0 37 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_I2C2>;
    status = "disabled";
};

i2c3: i2c@021a8000 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    compatible = "fsl,imx6q-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
    reg = <0x021a8000 0x4000>;
    interrupts = <0 38 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_I2C3>;
    status = "disabled";
};
```

*imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi*

```
&hdmi {
    ddc-i2c-bus = <&i2c1>;
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c1 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c2 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
    status = "okay";

    codec: sgtl5000@0a {
        compatible = "fsl,sgtl5000";
        reg = <0x0a>;
        clocks = <&clks 201>;
        VDDA-supply = <&reg_2p5v>;
        VDDIO-supply = <&reg_3p3v>;
    };
};
```

I see dts note entry for `sgtl5000` which is audio codec which then appears as `/dev/input/event0`. But I don't find any entry for 'prism' driver, which actually runs perfectly on the board. Neither dts files nor board-files have entry for 'prism' driver. But I am sure it's using 'device-tree' approach.

**Questions**

1. As my Wandboard works fine with 'prism' driver and touch device, why I don't see device node entry for 'prism' in dts files ?
2. Is there any other way for 'i2c device registration' other than 'device-tree' and 'earlier board-file' approach ?
3. How could I get past with ilitek touch driver not getting i2c-matched/registered problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After struggling to understand how i2c devices are registered and get known to the kernel, found out a very useful site which explains all 4 ways to instantiate i2c device. link: [Instantiate I2C devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices). In my device the 4th method from the site is being used to register i2c devices. Now, the touch screen driver reaches to it's `probe` function.

Comment: Your board quite likely uses Device Tree. So, when you define properly your device there it will go automatically.